# How to have the ## C functionality in python

Tags: python, preprocessor, protocol-buffers

In C, if you have a variable name and you have a variable you would like to access in protobuf

```
# define get_value(variable, variable_name, store){   \
    store = variable->name_variable_name    \
 }
```

Is there a similar functionality in python?

An alternative I can think of is just to do a large if else case

```
if protobuf_message.type = "LISTENER1":
    message = protobuf_message.LISTENER1
elif protobuf_message.listener2 = "LISTENER2":
    message = protobuf_message.LISTENER2
```

I would like to do something like this

```
listener_type = protobuf_message.type
message = protobuf_message.listener_type
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `getattr` function.

```
listener_type = protobuf_message.type
message = getattr(protobuf_message, listener_type)
```